# Pronunciation of the word "laboratory"

Tags: pronunciation

Can anyone please give a detailed pronunciation method for the word *laboratory*? I mean, is it labo-ra-tory or labo-ra-to-ry?

Answer (score 8):

Usually |ˈlæbrəˌtɔri| in American English and |ləˈbɒrətri| in British English

Comment: Also, we Americans have a tendency to shorten words, so "lab" is perfectly fine in informal speech.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laboratory) provides MP3 recordings.

Answer (score 0):

The CUVPlus electronic dictionary (based on the Oxford Learners' Dictionary) gives

laboratory: l@'b0r@trI (which is lə'bɒrətrɪ in IPA)

The CMUdict electronic dictionary (American English) gives

LABORATORY  L AE1 B R AH0 T AO2 R IY0

See [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/how-to-pronounce-new-orleans/2744#2744) for a link to the key to the pronunciation codes.